# pass variable to a method as a parameter

Tags: java, tapestry

I have following code in my tml file:

```
<t:loop source="navItem.subPages" value="var:subPage">
    <t:any element="li" class="prop:classForPageName">
        <t:pagelink page="var:subPage">${getMenuPageName(var:subPage)}</t:pagelink>
    </t:any>
</t:loop>
```

I have a problem to pass a variable `var:subPage` to method `${getMenuPageName(var:subPage)}`, as this throws an exception:

```
Could not convert 'getMenuPageName(var:subPage)' into a component parameter binding: Error parsing property expression 'getMenuPageName(var:subPage)': line 1:15 no viable alternative at input '('.
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, unfortunately that will not work, as this variable `value="var:subPage"` is created in scope of a loop. I've tried various things: with single quotes `${getMenuPageName('var:subPage')}`, `getMenuPageName('var:subPage')` none of this really works :/

Comment: Dmitry's answer is correct. Templates should be mostly just clean HTML with a sprinkling of references to properties. Also, the 'var' binding prefix is only useful in the simplest cases. Instead, change your loop to have source="subPage", create an actual subPage property in your Java class, change your getMenuPageName method to use that property instead of a passed-in parameter, and reference it in your html file as just ${menuPageName}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use [binding prefixes](http://tapestry.apache.org/component-parameters.html#ComponentParameters-BindingExpressions) (like `var:`) inside property expressions.

You may only use prefix in front of the expression to let Tapestry know how it should interpret the remainder (the part after the colon).

Refer to NBF grammar for property expressions to see what's allowed inside:

[Tapestry Documentation > User Guide > Property Expressions](https://tapestry.apache.org/property-expressions.html#PropertyExpressions-Grammar).

Property expressions were created to support just very basic constructs. If you need more complex expressions you should create corresponding methods in your java class and refer to them using the `prop:` binding prefix.

[Template expansions](https://tapestry.apache.org/component-templates.html#ComponentTemplates-Expansions) you've mentioned (`${...}`) work the same as parameter bindings:

> Under the covers, expansions are the same as parameter bindings. The
>   default binding prefix for expansions is "prop:" (that is, the name of
>   a property or a property expression), but other binding prefixes are
>   useful, especially "message:" (to access a localized message from the
>   component's message catalog).

Comment: But, this `getMenuPageName(String subPage)` is a method (returns String) not a property, why i can't pass variable as a parameter to it ? or how can i  ? - it doesn't make sense to me :/

Comment: Change the value binding to `value="subPage"`, in this case it will use default `prop:` binding, which means it will try to find a `@Property String subPage` in your java class.

Then change template expansion to `${getMenuPageName(subPage)}`.

Or alternatively you can directly use `subPage` property from `getMenuPageName` since it will be available there as a class field.

Comment: In the latter case you obviously shouldn't pass `subPage` via parameter, so declare your function as `getMenuPageName()` and invoke it with `${menuPageName}` as a regular getter/property.

Comment: Thanks! At the end that's only left solution. But I still don't get logic of creating temp variables as a class attributes/properties inside a class.. Isn't it odd ?